# Cross Communication between 2 websites

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to make a website which can tell college students their CGPA.
The students' grades come on our college website.
 It has got a login page for students to access their grades and other information.  (See Link 1 : Webkiosk)
Here is a login form like this :
(See Image 1)
The form has 2 Text Fields(Enrollment Number and Password), one dropdown menu(Member Type) and 2 buttons(Submit and Reset)
Submit Button : BTNSubmit
Reset Button  : BTNReset

Students have to login here and then go to this link for their grades (you will not be able to see it unless you are logged in) :
(See Link 2 : Grades)

Here again we need to select which grades you want, so I am giving a screenshot of this page.
(See Image 2)
Here we can see our grades. But the problem is that we don't get our CGPA, we have to calculate it manually. I have made a CGPA calculator for this (See Link 3 : Calculator) but in this calculator, user has to enter a lot of details.

So my idea was that I should make some calculator on web that only asks the user to enter his Enrollment Number and Password and then that calculator should do all the work.
The process involved would be : 
1. Get data from user in my form.
2. Transport this data to the college's website.
3. Extract grades from there.
4. Send them back to my calculator.
5. Calculate the CGPA and display it for the user.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

PS: StackOverFlow isn't allowing me to enter more than two links, so I would like you to visit this link for all the links and images.

[Links For Reference](https://clghelp.blogspot.in/2016/05/links-for-reference.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, you should set up a MySQL connection, then you can put the students grades into the MySQL databases, along with their Enrollment Number so the correct grades can be extracted once the user logs in, the extracted grades can then be processed through the calculator, then either display it directly to the user, or upload it into your own database, therefore the server doesn't have to process it all over again.

So in simple terms

User Login Request ---> MySQL Database ---> extracts grades ---> transports it to calculator ---> calculator calculates CGPA ---> sends back into the MySQL database ---> updates a column (can be called CGPA) ---> displays to user.

then you can make it check for new grades every week or so.

To have it calculated, you can do the following for the grades this is semi automated.

Grabs the grades from database then 
`<input name="gr1_1"><? echo $gradeUMA003; ?></input>`

there will have to be an active connection to the database with the grades in.

You will have to make an input for all of them, then create the Sql syntax to grab the subject grade. take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp for the help with creating that.

Then when the user visits the page, it automatically puts all the users grades in there, then when the user clicks calculate CGPA, it sends the results to the database meaning they wont have to do it when they next login. Therefore you can add on the page the CGPA grade of what they have got via the database. Once they have finished an exam, they will have to go back to the calculator and click submit again so it will update the database. Its a more easy manually done process therefore they don't have to keep putting in their grades all the time.